# Difference between ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected and elementSelectionStateToBe in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is  the Difference between ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected and elementSelectionStateToBe in selenium? How to use it? Can you give any example?

Answer (score 2):

ElementToBeSelected

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> elementToBeSelected(WebElement element)
```

ElementSelectionStateToBe

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> elementSelectionStateToBe(WebElement element, boolean selected)
```

As you can see from the methods signature `elementSelectionStateToBe` receives `boolean` as parameter. You can use this to check if the element is selected or not by passing parameter, while you need to catch an exception to check if the element isn't selected in `elementToBeSelected`.

To check if element is selected

```
// waits for the element to be selected
wait.until(ExpectedCondition.elementSelectionStateToBe(element, true)); 

// waits for the element to be selected
wait.until(ExpectedCondition.elementToBeSelected(element));
```

To check if element is not selected

```
// waits for the element **not** to be selected
wait.until(ExpectedCondition.elementSelectionStateToBe(element, false));

try {
    // waits for the element to be selected
    wait.until(ExpectedCondition.elementToBeSelected(element));
}
catch (TimeOutException)
{
    // the element is not selected
}
```

Comment: Just to add a little to this answer: 
ExpectedCondition.elementToBeSelected(element) actually calls ExpectedCondition.elementSelectionStateToBe(element, true): 

`public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> elementToBeSelected(final WebElement element) {
    return elementSelectionStateToBe(element, true);
  }` [src](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java)