# How to wait until dropdown selected text matches other text using selenium?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<select name="ddlFruit" id="ddlFruit" class="Searchddl">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="447">Grapes</option>
    <option value="448">Mango</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="449">Apple</option>
</select>
```

Suppose "Apple" is in first selected mode, due to some other actions on site, this drop-down changes to other options automatically. I want webdriver to wait until "Mango" text is in selected mode.

> Tried code:

```
public static SelectElement FindSelectElementWhenPopulated(IWebDriver driver, By by, int delayInSeconds, string optionText)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayInSeconds));
        return wait.Until<SelectElement>(drv => 
        {
            SelectElement element = new SelectElement(drv.FindElement(by));
            if (element.SelectedOption.ToString().Contains(optionText))
            {
                return element;
            }

            return null;
        }
        );
    }

Myclass.FindSelectElementWhenPopulated(driver, By.CssSelector("#ddlFruit"), 20, "Mango");
```

I am using C#.

Comment: Show us your current code and error traces

Comment: Updated plz check @JaSON

Comment: You can try to wait until element `//option[@selected="selected" and .="Mango"]` found

Comment: can you try this?
`wait.until(ExpectedCondition.elementSelectionStateToBe(element, true));` reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208638/difference-between-expectedconditions-elementtobeselected-and-elementselectionst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to convert the `SelectedOption` to a string. Test the `Text` property instead:

```
if (element.SelectedOption.Text.Contains(optionText))
```

With a few changes, you can make this a handy extension method on WebDriverWait:

```
public static SelectElement UntilOptionIsSelected(this WebDriverWait wait, By by, string optionText)
{
    return wait.Until<SelectElement>(driver => 
    {
        var element = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(by));

        if (element.SelectedOption.Text.Contains(optionText))
        {
            return element;
        }

        return null;
    });
}
```

And to use it:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var dropdown = wait.UntilOptionIsSelected(By.CssSelector("#ddlFruit"), "Mango");
```

Comment: Working: if (element.SelectedOption.Text.Contains(optionText))

Comment: @bydukaan: I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment.

Comment: Hi @Greg Bughardt , plz help me by solving this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084609/how-to-wait-until-javascript-fully-loaded-in-a-div-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Hi there, a similar type of problem. Plz help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104447/how-to-wait-until-div-dropdown-is-loaded-using-selenium-webdriver) @Greg Bughardt

Comment: Hi there, Could you please answer this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65999006/12826684). Thank you @greg-burghardt

Comment: Hi there, Could you please solve this issue.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65999006/12826684) Thank you @Greg Burghardt

Answer (score -3):

You need to use the `Select` class in Selenium:

```
Select dropdowns=new Select(driver.findelement(By.id("ddlFruit")));
dropdowns.selectByVisibleText("Mango");
```

Comment: This selects the drop-down, but i need wait until Mango text is selected

Comment: And this is written in Java, not C#.