# How to wait until div dropdown is loaded using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are two dropdown menus on a page.

When i click on First dropdown, then in second dropdown options will be automatically loaded after couple of seconds.

Here comes my problem, that how can i wait for the second dropdown to load fully using selenium webdriver.

```
<div name="ddlFruit_N" id="ddlFruit_N" class="Searchddl">
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">Select</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Apple</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Mango</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Grapes</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">Banana</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5">Guava</li>
</div>
```

> Note: This is div dropdown

Second dropdown list xpath: `//*[@id='ddlFruit_N']/div/ul/li`

Am using C# Thank you

Comment: can you please provide your DOM or URL ?

Comment: updated please check @SeleniumUser002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code. We will check for options to load in `Div`

```
public static IWebElement waitForDropdownPopulate(IWebDriver driver, By by, int delayInSeconds)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayInSeconds));
    return wait.Until<IWebElement>(drv => 
    {
        IWebElement elementList = drv.FindElement(by);
elementList.Click();
        if (elementList.FindElements(By.XPath("./div/ul//li")).Count >= 2)
        {
            return elementList;
        }

        return null;
    }
    );
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
Myclass.waitForDropdownPopulate(driver, By.XPath("//*[@id='ddlFruit_N']"), 30);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218646/discussion-on-answer-by-muzzamil-how-to-wait-until-div-dropdown-is-loaded-using).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var items = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='ddlFruit_N']/div/ul/li")))
        .FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ddlFruit_N']/div/ul/li"));
```

To use seleniumExtras library install DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers from NugetPackage

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, as @Muzzamil code working for me. BTW, thank you very much for sharing